# Possible to get user's photos in FB messenger extension using JS in webview?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, webview

I have a Facebook chat extension with a Webivew accessible via a persistent menu button.

On the Webview I load the messenger Extensions.js code and I can query for the user's page-scoped ID, permissions allowed, etc.

I'd like to be able to let the user share their photos, is there any way I can get access to that in the JS on my Webview? Or even on the server. Something like:

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<PAGE_SCOPED_USER_ID>?fields=photos,first_name,last_name,profile_pic,locale,timezone,gender&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

except the `photos` field doesn't work of course:

```
{u'error': {u'code': 100,
  u'fbtrace_id': u'xxxx/xxxxx',
  u'message': u'(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (photos) on node type (MessengerPageScopedID)',
  u'type': u'OAuthException'}}
```

I have the `user_profile` and `user_messaging` permissions currently.

So far I have only been able to get the standard fields ([listed here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile)) to work which are just first, last, gender, etc.

I'm fine with the user needing to allow more permissions (and clicking to add something), but I wanted to avoid a non-messenger auth flow like most FB apps. I assumed the point of messenger was to make less friction in that way.

I'm curious if I'm missing something or if there actually isn't a way to get other FB user data from Messenger chat extensions.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use Account linking. And have the user grant your app user_photos permission

Comment: I found a guide on [account linking](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking/v2.10), but I don't see anything about `user_photos` permission? or asking for specific permissions in general.

Comment: You need to have the user login using Facebook Login. Then you use account linking to connect their user ID with their page scoped user ID.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Facebook Login". They are already logged into facebook? Account linking with the messenger `Log In` button is described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking/link-account) and doesn't include references to what you're talking about.

Comment: Facebook Login as in log in to a 3rd-party app, and grant it permissions. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Comment: So messenger extensions don't provide any lower friction way to get user details than the way Facebook applications already work? How do I tie the extension to the application with the permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I've seen this done is to create your own Facebook Login page on the web using both the [Login Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/) and the [Messenger Extensions SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions/). Basically all you need to do is add both of these SDKs in the Javascript and create an html button for the user to press on to trigger the login. Don't forget to add the permissions you need to the Login SDK.

You can send a link to this login page via your bot in a url button. Make sure you enable Messenger Extensions on that button. When the user clicks on the button a webview will open with the Facebook login page you've created.

If the user is already logged in to Facebook they should just see a page asking them to accept the new permissions. Once they've accepted the permissions the page should return both the app-scoped-id (and an access token) as well as the page-scoped-id (Messenger id). You've now linked the app-scoped-id and the page-scoped-id and you can use this app-scoped-id and access token to query the Graph API for the permissions you asked for.

It's annoying having to take people out of the bot flow and into a webview but it's not a terrible user experience.